# git prevent push to master

Tags: git

This is my first time setting up a git server, so I don't really know what I am doing yet. Anyways, I have a git server setup with a user, What I want is to have multiple developers that can create their own branches and push the branches to origin, but I don't want them to push anything to master; an admin will merge after a code review. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) can do this for you. There's no way for you to set this up with the default git setup.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use Gitolite, add this to your `update` hook:

```
[ "$1" != refs/heads/master ] || {
    echo "ERROR:  you are not allowed to update master" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Won't this only allow pushing to master, not the other way around?

Comment: @daramarak: No, notice the `||`.  It's expressed as an assertion:  "the ref is not master, or else error out."  I did it that way instead of `[ "$1" = refs/heads/master ] && { ... }` because assertion style is idiomatic for shell scripting (it makes error handling easier).

Comment: Ah, I see. Not to used to read bash scripting. A bit confusing. Was comparing this to an another answer. Anyway this should have been the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Extending the answer of Richard a bit: Use the following snippet as your "hooks/update" and pushing to master will only be allowed to the user with the name "git-repo-admin":

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $USER != "git-repo-admin" ];
then
  if [ "$1" == refs/heads/master ];
  then
    echo "Manual pushing to this repo is restricted"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

Comment: This won't work where my origin is set to git@someserver.com:/git/main.git, as $USER will always be "git".

Comment: USER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --format=format:%ae HEAD)
USER_NAME=$(git log -1 --format=format:%an HEAD)

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/58346/any-tricks-to-get-the-authenticated-user-in-git-hook-script